# How to get time from web service when data is retrieved?

Tags: android, web-services

I can retrieve data from webservice, but now i want to know/get time, the data is sent from web service. The time the data is received from web service. Not the local device time. In other words, the web service should pack time along with the data on call of webservice method.

Comment: You might want to add some info about the web service since that's what you're really asking about

Answer (score 0):

As per the WS itself, the only way to do so would be with the WS implementing a method that returns that value.

OTOH, you can try looking for the value in the HTTP headers of the WS reply.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes i figured that way, i just thought if there was any other way.